# Advantage of making a List to a ReadOnlyCollection or AsReadOnly

Tags: c#, data-structures

```
List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();
dinosaurs.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");
```

1. Why should I use a `ReadOnlyCollection` as follows:

   ```
   var readOnlyDinosaurs = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(dinosaurs);
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   dinosaurs.AsReadOnly();
   ```
2. What is the real advantage of making a List to a ReadOnlyCollection or a AsReadOnly?

Comment: Not really a "full answer", hence why this is a comment. Calling .AsReadOnly(); is another method call, which in turns put additional overhead on the program. It's minimal, but it's there. Especially if this is used in some sort of batch (repetitive) application.

Comment: @Jim that's nonsense. It puts `this` on the stack and then calls the constructor. Such a small method will normally be inlined by the jitter. The only overhead will be on when the method containing the call is first jitted, and that overhead will be tiny.

Comment: Exactly why I said it's minimal... I didn't think about compile time optimizations though.

He asked for differences, and this is one difference albeit very minimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, they are the same, [as mentioned by Erwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12185429/1159478).  There is one important case where they differ though.  Because the `AsReadOnly` method is generic, the type of the newly created `ReadOnlyCollection` is infered, not specifically listed.  Normally this just saves you a bit of typing, but in the case of anonymous types it actually matters.  If you have a list of anonymous objects you need to use `AsReadOnly`, rather than `new ReadOnlyCollection<ATypeThatHasNoName>`.

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference, if you look at the code of AsReadOnly():

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<T> AsReadOnly()
{
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They're equivalent in functionality - but only because you're starting with a `List<T>`.

The constructor form can be done with any `IList<T>`, so is the only option in some cases. The other form is a tad more concise, and to some minds (I would agree) a bit nicer in describing just what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use readonly collection in case when you want to **guarantee** that none can change that *collection*. Which is, by the way, doesn't mean that caller will not be able to change the *content* of that collection.

```
var collection = List<object> {new SomeObject{...},
               new SomeObject{..}}; //SOME OBJECT IS REFERENCE TYPE    
var readonly =  new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(collection );    
readonly[0].SomeObjectProperty = SomeValue; //HERE ORIGINAL OBJECT IS CHANGED
```

As others said , there is no difference between those 2 calls present in the question.

Comment: Your example uses reserved words.